# SQL - sum of the subtraction from previous rows (row by row)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm having problem with SQL.

- Column a - date when the product from a given delivery expires
- Column b - quantity in delivery
- Column c - cumulative product deliveries
- Column d - cumulative product sales to given expire date

I need to calculate how many products from any delivery expired, because it wasn't sold in time using FIFO method. So, based on given example, from first delivery all was sold, from second delivery only 1 product was sold and 3 expired, from third delivery all products expired, from fourth delivery all products was sold, from fifth delivery only 2 products was sold and 3 expired etc.

I've tried using sum() over but it's summing column b and c and then subtract them in total, not row by row.

I think what I want to achieve is some kind of a loop (because it's based on result's from previous rows calculations), unfortunately I don't know how to make loops, so please help me :).

I'm using snowflake.

[image: Example]

Comment: I don't think you want 'previous rows' I think you want 'earlier dates' there's quite a difference

Comment: yes, earlier dates, sorry.

Comment: if that's the case you don't need a loop, you just need a subquery that filters on date

Comment: I don't undestand. Screen from example is my table, i have a list of all deliveries and for each delivery i have to calculate how many products will expire, but i also need to know how many product expired before that date. For example products from one of deliveries will expire 2020-11-09 (row 5) and until that day only 15 product was sold, while sum of all deliveries was 29, so i need to check how many products already expired from previous deliveries and take that to calculation and then my result should be: from this delievery 3 out of 5 products expired.

Comment: The value of `calculation` can definitely be computed using recursive query (the row with min `a` is the seed row, the next closest row is computed using formula you described verbosely, probably using `case when` statement to represent `result>0` condition). However, if I were you, I would first try to derive some explicit formula to compute calculation. Since `calc1=d1-c1`, `calc2=d2-c2-calc1`, `calc3=d3-c3-(calc2+calc1)=d3-c3-(d2-c2)`, `calc4=d4-c4-(d3-c3)` etc., rough running value can be computed as `d-c - (lag(d-c) over (order by a)`. Sanitization to `>0` makes it harder though.